# Android Annotations + multiple paths to APT

Tags: android, android-annotations, android-apt

imagine some proyect like [this one](https://github.com/josejuanmontiel/SmartConfig) that use android-annotations and for this work i have to put this in build.gradle

```
apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName "com.pandaos.smartconfig"
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}
```

where: **resourcePackageName "com.pandaos.smartconfig"**

its the path where code its annotated... the config for plugin [android-apt](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt)

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

I suppose, that plugin "invoke" some task to generate the code that android-annotations create under the hood, but...

Its possible define multiple "packages in the app"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resourcePackageName` comes from the configuration option for [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/CustomizeAnnotationProcessing#resourcepackagename):

> By default, AndroidAnnotations try to find the `R` class by extracting 
>   application package from `AndroidManifest.xml` file. But in some cases you 
>   may want to specify a custom package to look for the R class. This is why
>   we added `resourcePackageName` option.

There are two things to note:

1. The option refers to the Android package name, which does not have to be the same as your *java* package name.
2. The `R` package name can be different from the Android package name you set in `AndroidManifest.xml` if you use the [`applicationId`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) option in the Gradle build file.

It's totally fine to have a different *java* package name in your code. AFAIK this will not influence AndroidAnnotations in any way.

The `apt` block is provided by the `android-apt` plugin and allows you to configure *any* parameter to annotation processors in your project. In this case it configures the parameters that AndroidAnnotations need to do its job. The `android-apt` plugin serves two purposes in this case: it configures the parameters for the AndroidAnnotations processor, and it will make sure you can reference the sources that are generated by AA in Android Studio.

Comment: Well, you perfectly explained ;) may during migration from "nothing" to gradle in this project... i put resourcePackegeName without knowing what i was doing, and later it when need new package, this limite where AA look for annotation, i try differents approach, and AA do its work, one tip more, in sourceSet java.srcDirs = ['build/source/apt/debug'] not necesary andoid-apt do its work there too